# Implementation of Singly-Linked List from Loudon's Algorithm Book

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I am reading *Mastering Algorithms with C* by Kyle Loudon, and currently I am struggling with Loudon's implementation of Singly-Linked List in Chapter 5.

Here are the links to the source code. I apologize for not posting them here as they are a bit long.

[list.h](https://github.com/kangnahua/matering-algirhtms-with-c/blob/master/list.h)

[list.c](https://github.com/kangnahua/matering-algirhtms-with-c/blob/master/list.c)

My question is related to the `destroy` in **list.c** as it is mentioned in line **11** under

`void list_init(List* list, void (*destroy)(void* data))`

as `list->destroy = destroy`

and then again in line **24** as

`list->destroy(data)`.

All I know is that this `destroy` is different from the function `list_destroy` but I have no idea what it is. Is it a function or is it just a pointer? What purpose does it serve in the `list_init()` function for initializing a linked list?

I really appreciate your time and help! The source code is linked above.

Comment: You indicated the problem was solved by accepting an answer. Please don't add "Solved" to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a function pointer. When you create an instance of this list, you also have to hand the init_list function a function which it will use to destroy the info.

The purpose of a linked list is to store information, and the linked list structure is there to give some structure to
this data. Hence, each element of the list contains a pointer to some data, and a pointer to the next element in the list. However, you want the list to able to handle multiple kinds of data.

Suppose you want to remove an element of the list, then there are basically two things that have to happen:

1. The data needs to be destroyed
2. The linked list structure must be restored. Meaning that the predecessor of the element you removed must point to
   the next element in the list.

Since you do not know beforehand what kind of data the data pointer in the list will contain, for step 1 a function pointer is provided to handle the destroying of that data.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good suggestion. I have used it to improve the answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. I think it will take some more time for me to read C comfortably.

Comment: Florian, I have another question: If *destroy is the function pointer that could be set to free to free malloc-ed data, why do we put (void* data) instead of just "data" as the parameter? Is this void serving the purpose of all-types-allowed? Thanks.

Comment: Do note that the paratmer is a void _pointer_. But indeed, this serves the purpose of all types allowed. The destroy function is passed the void pointer to the data, and the destroy function will know that to do with it. As an example, if it was actually storing ints, you would pass the list_init a function that would cast the void pointer to an int pointer to be able to free the data.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a data structure made up of nodes, each of which contains or links to one piece of data.

The `destroy` function destroys just one node out of the list.

The `list_destroy` function destroys an entire list.

In the given implementation, the node actually contains a pointer to its `destroy` function, and accesses it by dereferencing that pointer.  As it happens (so far), all nodes point to the same destroy function.  But with more complex data structures this pattern allows multiple types of nodes to be in the data structure.  And the equivalent of the `list_destroy` function will correctly destroy each node type correctly since the node knows how it should be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It helps me to understand the code much better now.